# Python dpath.util.get Empty string keys Error

Tags: python, json, dpath

I read in a simple JSON text file and it parses to a dict just fine.

```
>>> data.keys()
dict_keys(['metadata', 'value'])
```

I want to get specific elements and I typically use the dpath package. However, in this case i get an error which seems to imply that I

```
dpath.util.get(data, 'metadata', separator='..')
InvalidKeyName: Empty string keys not allowed without dpath.options.ALLOW_EMPTY_STRING_KEYS=True
```

I don't see any empty string keys, only the two above. I can reproduce with some other seemingly random JSON text files but for others it works just fine. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Did you try to debug the library code? It must make it clear what specifically it doesn't like.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ . I can only make guesses if you don't give me anything concrete to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Searching this error message in the library's codebase](https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Empty%20string%20keys%20not%20allowed%20without) finds [`dpath/path.py:88`](https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python/blob/2d9117c5fc6870d546aadefb5bf3ab194f4c7411/dpath/path.py#L88):

```
    for (k, v) in iteritems:
        if issubclass(k.__class__, (string_class)):
            if (not k) and (not dpath.options.ALLOW_EMPTY_STRING_KEYS):
                raise dpath.exceptions.InvalidKeyName("Empty string keys not allowed without "
                                                      "dpath.options.ALLOW_EMPTY_STRING_KEYS=True")
```

So, this error is raised when your data structure has empty keys.

Comment: I shared my data.keys(). You can see that there are two keys, no empty keys. That is what is confusing. Thanks!

Comment: @Max There could be somewhere lower in the hierarchy. Maybe the lib looks through the entire hierarchy, I didn't bother looking. If you debug the code, you'll see what exactly it chokes on.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is a known issue, not sure if it getting fixed or not https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python/issues/73

Comment: @Max Your error doesn't look like anything in that ticket. My previous statement stands. Without the means to reproduce the error, I can't say anything else.

Comment: It is the issue. I had a sub element with and empty string as the key value. Sorry, not well described in the issue. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Looks like there is a fork with a fix: https://github.com/streamsets/dpath-python/commit/a73be9d6eec788ee1a3d8b16df2163ba111afac7